# Linear differential equations question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As I understand it, the differential equation

$$y^{(n)} + p_1(t)y^{(n-1)} + ... + p_{(n-1)}(t)y^{(1)} = f$$

is linear because the left hand side can be written as $L[y]$ where $L$ is a linear operator.  So why isn't

$$p_0(t)y^{(n)} + p_1(t)y^{(n-1)} + ... + p_{n-1}(t)y^{(1)} = f$$

considered linear?

Comment: Who says it isn't?

Comment: Well my textbook said that a linear differential equation is of the form $y^{(n)} + p_1(t)y^{(n-1)} + ... + p_{(n-1)}(t)y^{(1)} = f$ which led me to believe that only differential equations like that were linear.

Comment: So $y'=y$ isn't linear, even though it's the same as $y'-y=0$, which is linear?

Comment: My question was whether $p_0(t)$ could be in front of $y^n$

Comment: Your question was whether it had to look exactly like what's in the book for it to be linear. $y'=y$ doesn't look exactly like what's in the book. Does that mean it isn't linear?

Comment: Well, $p_i(t) = 0$.

Comment: If $p_i(t)$ is identically zero, then you have $y^{(n)}=f$ where presumably $f$ is a function of $t$, not of $y$. So you don't get $y'=y$ by letting some coefficient(s) vanish.

Answer (score 1):

The second equation is linear as well. In general, a differential equation is linear, if $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ both satisfy the homogeneous differential equation, then so does $\alpha y_1(t) + \beta y_2(t)$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ i.e. if $L(y_1(t)) = 0$ and $L(y_2(t)) = 0$, then we also have that $$L(\alpha y_1(t) + \beta y_2(t)) = 0$$